# Apache camel - Same source for two sequential executed routes

Tags: java, apache-camel

I would like to execute two routes sequencial from same route.

In other words, i would like to launch this execution flow:

```
from("route1")-->
    to("route2") //executed with output of route1 as source
    to("route3") //executed with output of route1 as source and executed after route2 finish
```

How can be this done with apache camel?

Kind regards

Comment: in your route2 get the body from route 1 and then after processing inside route2, set the same body from route1 to exchange.getIn

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do.

```
from("route1")
    .to("route2")
    .to("route3");

from("route2").process(exchange -> {

  Object body = exchange.getIn().getBody();
  // Processing logic......
  // Make sure you don't change the state of body.
  exchange.getIn().setBody(body);
});

from("route3").process(exchange -> {
  //This will have body from route1
  Object body = exchange.getIn().getBody();
})
```

You could use multicast or wiretap, but that doesn't help you to keep the order of excecution, i.e. route3 after route2.

Comment: And you can use the direct component for these routes, to route between them, eg "direct:route2", "direct:route3" etc.

Comment: The real system it is a little bit more complicated than i've explained, because route2 are more than ten routes distributed in different proyects (i've explain it as one route to simplify the example). So the idea of propagating the body it is complicated to make because in these routes body changes. Isn't there other way to make it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the [recipient list](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/recipientList-eip.adoc) is what you're looking for.  Each recipient receives a copy of the original exchange.  The default behaviour is sequential.

For example:

```
from("direct:route1")
    .recipientList("direct:route2,direct:route3");
```

Comment: i do apologize because i forgot this pattern. This is the solution. Thanks